# Can Rich Text Area Field in SF be used in JB if so what is the what is the character limits

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can Rich Text Area Field in SF be used in Journey(MC) if so what is the what is the character limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a limit of 4K Characters in the MC. If the field limit is more than 4K that then JB throws a warning " **This event contains data fields that are too large to allow processing to complete. Remove at least one field to proceed**"

Comment: mind linking the documentation?

Comment: The 4k limit applies to data extensions in general. Documentation is here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5

Comment: A rich text field requirement sounds like a personalization case. For journey builder sends with typically low send volumes you can resort to the RetrieveSalesforceObjects AMPSCRIPT function to get the information at send time: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm.